# Iterate through map data within a nested sub-map

Tags: flutter, dart

Our app receives nested JSON data from Firebase. We store this data in List of Object Item & Object Order.

Object Order can have multiple attributes, int price; List item; itemDecription. Sublist item can have multiple strings of itemName.

When we  attempt to access itemName, in rasterMap, it is only accessing the last item in the list. How can we access multiple all values of itemName in rasterMap?

Our data structure is:

```
{
    "Orders": {
        "-MPuETb4vq2NdtQl-_y1": {
            "name": "Pulled Pork Sandwich",
            "price": 14.00

        },
        "-fbdhfunshy-_y2": {
            "name": "BBQ Spare Ribs",
            "price": 14.00

        }
    }
}
----Begin code---

//List to create orderItem with object item
    List<Item> orderItems = []; 
//List to create orderList with object item
    List<Order> orderList = [];


//Retrieve JSON
//Firebase connection here
 if (!_checkIfObjectExist(orderDate)) {
    Item itemObj = Item.fromJson(event.documents[i].data);
        orderItems.add(itemObj);
    Order orderObj = Order.fromJson(event.documents[i].data);

}
//iterate through order list 
  for (int i = 0; i < orderList.length; i++ ) {
      print(orderList);
      for(int j = 0; j < orderList[i].item.length; j++) {
        itemName = orderList[i].item[j].itemName;
        print(itemName);
      }
  }

Map<String, dynamic> rasterMap = {
          'appendBitmapText':
        "LIST ITEM NAMES IN THIS STRING MAP HERE"
        };
```

Comment: Can you publish a sample JSON data (not short, pls)?

Comment: First, your data has some errors; second, can you publish properly it in your message above? better if it is complete data or a link

Comment: @Ουιλιαμ Αρκευα

Thank you - I edited the comment above. Any thoughts?

Comment: Bro, when handling any data you need to verify its integrity and correctness before anything else. There are any errors, specially with `[0]` or `[1]`. You can use this [online validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com#) to view those errors. I have experience working with Json data but not so much with Firebase.

Comment: After verifying the JSON data, how can the data be iterated and added to as a list of strings in rasterMap?

Comment: I see you have modified your JSON data, and it is OK. In your current structure for key `Orders` its value is a type of `Map<String, dynamic>`, I'd change it to `List<MapEntry<String, dynamic>>` or `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, it will depend on if there are duplicate items, and with that you can iterate more easily, if you want use your current structure, then you can use property `keys` for Map class and to iterate with it.

Comment: You can use `map` method too.

Comment: I'm confused by your approach here. How will the iteration of the key/value pairs of ` "itemName": "String Item Name" in a list be accessible and called in Map<String, dynamic> rasterMap? I understand that the instance of Order will be returned but I don't see how accessing the Key/Value pair of itemName in rasterMap is done?

In my approach, I can iterate and print the itemNames but only one 1 itemName is returned itemName.toString() is called in rasterMap. I'm not seeing how this is called in your approach?

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'dart:convert';

// your current structure
const rawData = '''
{
  "Orders": {
    "-MPuETb4vq2NdtQl-_y1": {
      "name": "Pulled Pork Sandwich",
      "price": 14.00
    },
    "-fbdhfunshy-_y2": {
      "name": "BBQ Spare Ribs",
      "price": 14.00
    }
  }
}
''';

// My suggestion for your structure
const rawData2 = '''
{
  "Orders": [
    {
      "id": "-MPuETb4vq2NdtQl-_y1",
      "name": "Pulled Pork Sandwich",
      "price": 14.00
    },
    {
      "id": "-fbdhfunshy-_y2",
      "name": "BBQ Spare Ribs",
      "price": 14.00
    }
  ]
}
''';


class Order {
  String? id, name;
  double? price;

  Order.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    price = json['price'];
  }
}


void main(List<String> args) {
  final data = jsonDecode(rawData2)['Orders'] as List;
  var orders = <Order>[];
  
  data.forEach((m) => orders.add(Order.fromJson(m as Map<String, dynamic>)));
  print(orders);
}
```

Result:

```
[Instance of 'Order', Instance of 'Order']
```